# Loading and Playing audio files

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to load an audio file using the `InputStream` class. My audio file is located in the `src` folder. I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at line 2 (sysout line).

```
InputStream audioStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/buttonSound.mp3");
System.out.println(audioStream.toString());
Media buttonSound = null;
try {
    buttonSound = MediaManager.createMedia(audioStream, "audio/mp3");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a better way to load and play audio files in codenameone? Í read the [developer manual](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html) but that did not help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the following line to create a MediaPlayer object:

private MediaPlayer mediaplayer= new MediaPlayer;

mediaplayer=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.NAMEOFYOURMP3FILE);

mediaplayer.start();

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a null stream that means the file wasn't found. Make sure it's in the src directory and not in one of the directories under it. Also make sure the case matches and there are no spaces in the file name.